# How to add font-family 'Open Sans' to inline svg text?

Tags: html, svg, inline, google-fonts

How to add two words name of font-family (as 'Open Sans') to inline svg text ?

```html
<svg viewbox='0 24 100 24' fill='#000'>
  <text font-size='24' fill='#000' font-family='Open+Sans'>MENU</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the plus symbols; those are only needed when the font name is included in a URL.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 30">
    <text x="0" y="27" font-size="30" fill="#fa0"
          font-family="Comic Sans MS">MENU</text>
</svg>
```

If you want to add fallback alternatives, add quotation marks like this:

```
font-family="'Comic Sans MS',cursive"
```